# Problem with width of column of DevExpress ASPXGridView Control

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I'm new in the asp.net as well as devexpress asp.net controls. I'm developing one website, for that i used the master page & added some other web pages which uses master page. In one web page i used the Devexpress's ASPXPageControl & in that page control i created multible pages . I used the Devexpress ASPXGridView control & i added required columns to that grid & bind that grid at runtime means at page load event with the table.

While designing the columns i set the width property of the column, but it not giving me the required width when i'm actually running the web page.

I don't know why it is not showing the proper width.

How to solve this issue?

thanks.

Comment: i solved this question . for solving this i set the width of the grid equal to the sum of width of all columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this question . for solving this i set the width of the grid equal to the sum of width of all columns.

Answer (score 0):

is your rendered column width more than the width you specified? if so, try setting `CellStyle-Wrap="true"`